# How to create a shortcut which only Toast something when I touched it

Tags: android, android-activity, shortcut

I want to create a shortcut in Android, and when I touch it, it will only do something silently such as `Toast` something. But I found that it will display the main `Activity`. How could I get it to run silently?

Just like the *AdvancedTaskManager*'s shortcut~Click and then `Toast`.

Thanks.

At the moment, I've got:

```
public class ShortcutOnclickActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String tag = ShortcutOnclickActivity.class
                                                            .getSimpleName();
    public static final String ACTION_SHORTCUT_CLICKED = ShortcutOnclickActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(tag, "Clicked!");
        finish();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return;
    }   
}

<!-- Shortcut -->
<activity android:name=".ShortcutActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity-alias android:name="CreateShortcutActivity"
        android:targetActivity=".ShortcutActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
        </category>
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
<activity android:name=".ShortcutOnclickActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.androidesk.ShortcutOnclickActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
        </category>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I think Activity is not appropriate.
Maybe you are looking for an AppWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i had the same problem.
I have found a solution:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setVisible(false);
    finish();
    return;
}
```

This will start the Activity normaly but will hide the window (make it invisible).

hope this helps.

best regards,
PrDatur